# cv2.VideoCapture() can't find my usb webcam

Tags: python, opencv, camera, video-capture

I wanted to enable my webcam using opencv in python but i keep getting error:
"(-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'"

I tried to change the camera index in VideoCapture() to different numbers, but nothing worked. Only when I put the number 0 there, the led light in my webcam turned on, but the code still did not work. I'm new at this so please show me my mistake.
the code was like this:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.isOpened()

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    print(ret)
    cv2.imshow('hui obnaruzhen', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this *ret* thing showed *False*, so that's why i think the problem is in cv2.VideoCapture()

Comment: **VideoCapture** has the device index or the name of a video file. The device index is just an integer to define a Camera. If we pass 0, it is for the first or primary camera, 1 for the second camera so try to pass 1 inside `cv2.VideoCapture`

Comment: What if you changed cv2.waitKey(0) or cv2.waitKey(1) and VideoCapture(0) or VideoCapture(1)? Also if not ret: break

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but you have to be sure that you could read a frame before show it. If you see the error, it is in the "imshow" function. Try to add a line before "imshow" function with: "if(ret):".